# NicEdit font and json

Tags: json, nicedit

I'm using nicEdit text editor in my app and I'm facing two issues.

1. How can I changes the default font-family/size for the text editor that is controlled by nicEdit. I've my font properties in style attribute of the text editor, but that doesn't seem to work.
2. I've json2.js (that I got from www.json.org) imported in the same page that has nicEdit.js.
   When I open this page, the font tag images (like bold[B] ) at the start gets repeated multiple times. What could be the commonality between json.js and nicEdit.js that's causing this, and the work-around?

Appreciate all your help.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. I've never heard of `nicEdit` but probably it has its own `CSS` theme. Change it there instead of inline.

Answer (score 1):

To set the font family and size:

At line# 428 of nicEdit.js (where 'var s' is initialized with the style properties of the text area), add this: fontSize: '14px', fontFamily: 'arial' (or something that you desire).

If you don't like this hard-coding and if you want it to get it from the elements' style itself, use this:

theFontFamily = e.getStyle('fontFamily') || e.style.fontFamily

theFontSize = e.getStyle('fontSize') || e.style.fontSize;

and at the same line stated above, use these variables.